# Powering Power Delivery device with non-PD cable/splitter

Tags: usb, usb-c, usb-power-delivery

I know that USB-C splitters don't follow the USB spec, but I have an use case where I actually need to run one cable, but get two USB-C cables out. Neither will have data, but they will have power, however, not Power Delivery.

I have a 15.6" touch screen that has a female USB-C port named "PD". There is no spec on the port (because cheap and no-name), but the screen only takes 5v (confirmed). The other USB-C port on the monitor takes data + video. If I connect my phone, it will:

1. Power the screen @ 5v
2. Power phone @ 9v
3. Receive video from phone
4. Send touch input to phone

I want to run 1 cable into an Y-splitter, however, it should only output 5v. The screen takes 5v and all my other USB-C gadgets (Raspberry Pi) take 5v minimum as well. I could make an Y-splitter (I actually did), however, the screen will not power on, unless it negotiates with the charger.. even though it runs at 5v.

What options do I have? I want to run 1 cable, power the screen (at 5v but via PD), and power a device with 5v (PD or no PD - does not matter). The plugs I use to make USB-C things are these:

[image]

Comment: Doubt that it's a good idea. A Pi (4) alone barely works with the maximum 3A that can be provided with 5V.

Comment: @TomYan A Pi 4 doesn't draw 3A though. The 3A power supply is for if you have USB devices plugged in as well. Source: I've run a Pi 4 with an SSD attached for over a year. If you have nothing plugged in and you run a heavy benchmark, it barely draws 1.5A. On the other hand, the screen can be powered from my phone. One cable to power the screen, transfer video, and touch as well.